# If $\left| \frac{z-i}{z-1}\right| = \sqrt2$ and $|z| = \sqrt 5$ and $Im(z)<0$, find $Im(z)$, $Re(z)$

Tags: complex-numbers

I'm having a lot of problem with the first term. If I try to rationalize the fraction, I get an expression too long to work with. Similarly, substituting from the second term gives horrible results.

Breaking the modulus apart and squaring gives me an incorrect result, and I just don't know how to approach the problem anymore. I'm probably making a dumb mistake along the lines, but I'd be grateful if someone could solve this step by step.

EDIT: Wrote the thing incorrectly, switched the denominator and enumerator. Sorry for anyone who solved the wrong thing, but they should be similar enough for a simple switch, no?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. If you square the first term, you will get what you have written.

Comment: See updated answer........

Answer (score 2):

If $z=a+ib$ then $a^{2}+b^{2}=5$ is the second equality, and the first equality is $$a^{2}-2a+1+b^{2}=2(a^{2}+b^{2}-2b+1),$$
which is equivalent to $a^{2}+b^{2}-4b+2a+1=0$. Substitute the first to the second to get $-4b+2a+6=0$. Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 1):

$$\left| \frac{z-1}{z-i}\right|^2 = 1/2$$

$$\implies \frac{z-1}{z-i}\frac{\bar{z}-1}{\bar{z}+i}=1/2$$

$$\implies \frac{|z|^2-(z+\bar{z})+1}{|z|^2+i(z-\bar{z})+1}=1/2$$

$$\implies \frac{5-2\Im(z)+1}{5-2\Re (z)+1}=2$$

$$\implies 2(5-2\Re (z)+1)=5-2\Im(z)+1$$

$$6-4\Re (z)+2\Im(z)=0$$

$$\implies \Re(z)=3/2\text{ and } \Im(z)=0$$

Comment: Afraid that's not quite the solution.

Comment: @@ John Doe):I think in your condition $\Im(z)<0$ is absurd. It will be $\Im(z)\le 0$ ..

Comment: Crap, the -1 and -i are supposed to be switched around. I knew something was off. I'm sorry.

Comment: OK...Then it is still $\Im(z)=0$..